# android can't read all website source code

Tags: java, android

I'm using that code in android studio to read this("http://www.posh24.com/celebrities") website but it only read a few line of the source page it stops exactly after reaching this string "

```html
</div>
                  <div class="channelListEntry">
                 <a href="/justin_bieber">
                  <div clas
```

this is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GetString getString = new GetString();
    String gr = null;

    try {
         gr = getString.execute("http://www.posh24.com/celebrities").get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and

```
  public class GetString extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(params[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: What is the length of the `result` String ? You can't have more than 2^31 - 1 character (Integer.MAX_VALUE) in theory but seems to be only 65535. Note : Don't use String concatenation in those while loop but a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: PS : It simply crash on `<a href="/justin_bieber">`, I don't believe in coincidence !!!

Comment: `gr = getString.execute("http://www.posh24.com/celebrities").get();` Very bad coding using the `.get()` on an AsyncTask instance. remove it and handle the result of `doInBackground()` in a normal way in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: `data = reader.read();`. Do not read one char at the time with all those conversions. Use `reader.readLine()` to read lines. Add the readed lines to a StringBuilder instance.

Comment: thank you for your help but I used StringBuilder and the same result.

Comment: I can't use doInBackground() method directly 
and i can't find readLine method in InputStreamReader Class